mod operation working differently in XSLT1.0
I have the requirement to do the modulo operation in XSLT1.0. But, it's not returning expected result which is working fine in Java.
XSLT1.0:
Input:
<xsl:variable name="num2" select="'501108006111600075131466'"/>
<xsl:variable name="num3" select="'3214282912345698765432161182'"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$num2 mod 97"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$num3 mod 97"/>

Output:
82
65

Java
Input
StringBuilder numeric = new StringBuilder();
numeric.append(501108006111600075131466);//Input1
//numeric.append(3214282912345698765432161182);//Input2
BigInteger nt = new BigInteger(numeric.toString());
return nt.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(97)).intValue() == 1;

Output
true
true

In Java, returned expected result but in XSLT1.0 it's not return exact output. Is there any other way to implement mod operator in XSLT1.0?

The problem is that the numeric expressions in your XSLT 1.0 code will use XPath 1.0 numbers, which are only double-precision floating-point numbers, with insufficient precision to represent the large numbers in your example. The least significant digits of your numbers will be lost.

Consider to use numeric types, not strings, but for numbers that large you might need to switch to XSLT/XPath 2 or 3 where you have the xs:integer and xs:decimal type e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:variable name="num1" as="xs:integer" select="501108006111600075131466"/>
  <xsl:variable name="num2" as="xs:integer" select="3214282912345698765432161182"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <tests>
      <test expression="{$num1} mod 97">{$num1 mod 97}</test>
      <test expression="{$num2} mod 97">{$num1 mod 97}</test>
    </tests>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

gives
<tests>
   <test expression="501108006111600075131466 mod 97">1</test>
   <test expression="3214282912345698765432161182 mod 97">1</test>
</tests>

